# ggplot barplot knitted with R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, geom-bar

Problem: The labels of the y-axis of this plot are too close too each other.

Question: How can I increase the spacing between labels?

[image]

Comment: Make the plot bigger, make the font smaller, show fewer labels. Not rotating your xaxis labels will give you a smidgeon more space.

Comment: @RichardTelford, how can I make the plot bigger? Ideally I can make the plot vertically longer, do you know how?

Comment: you can set the fig.height in the chunk options

Comment: @RichardTelford! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the fig.height in your rmd chunck.
Sample

````
```{r, warning=FALSE,message=FALSE, fig.height=12, fig.width=12}
# Your ggplot code goes over here

```
````